# what data is used for `toDataURL` to export a base64 URI string

Tags: javascript, canvas, encoding, base64

I try to implement `toDataURL`, and here's what I did:

1. create base64 encoder according to its spec. There's a encoder source on [wiki](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Algorithm_Implementation/Miscellaneous/Base64#Javascript)
2. draw image to canvas, and get image data with `getImageData(0,0, width, height)
3. encode the `rgba` data to base64 use the encoder.

But the result is different to output of standard `canvas.toDataURL`. So far I think the problem may be the `rgba` data. But I am not sure.

Here's the demo on [codepen](https://codepen.io/maple-leaf/pen/BJYXwO)

**Edit**

After spending some time on studying png algorithm, I try to implement it, but the data problem appear again.
According to png spec, I can use `rgba` as data part of `IDAT` while I set `color type` of `IHDR` to `6` and `depth` to `8`. And then I analysis the base64 code of img by decoding it(you can find log in demo), everything goes good but data length.

[image]

The picture show the length of `IDAT` is only **30**, but length of data output by `getImageData` of canvas is **100**.

Why `rgba` data in `base64` is different to the data by `getImageData`?

Comment: Share a simple version of your code implementation.

Comment: @N-ate thanks for reply. I have updated my question and add a codepen link.

Comment: What is the expected input to `base64_encode` function?

Comment: @guest271314 for my encoder function of given codepen, it receive `imagedata` from function `getImageData`. In general, base64 encoder transform `8-bit` binary to `6-bit` binary, and then translate to `character` according to mapping. So maybe `8-bit` binary is answer for you question.

Comment: @guest271314 yes.

Comment: I've been tinkering around with this. I've been able to confirm that most of your code is working. It seems that the data returned from getImageData is not the same format as the original image. It has many more bytes and seems to be only pixel data. Whereas the original image seems to have other bytes included. You may need to look into image file formats to figure out what is going on. Perhaps you need a particular byte wrapper that describes the pixel bytes?

Comment: The base64 data returned by toDataURL is the one of the image file, not of the raw pixel data. So if e.g you chose the default file type 'image/png', it will represent an png image file, with all the headers, and DEFLATEd image data. So to implement this method, you would have to first implement a png encoder, a jpeg one, and a webp one. But even then you would probably not have the same results as there are many options that can be set (e.g compression level) and which are implementation dependents.

Comment: @Kaiido Got it. Thanks. :-)

Comment: @Kaiido I study some png things and update my question. would you mind to take sometime to help me out. Thanks :-)